# Can AWS Lambda be used as the backend for getstream.io?

Tags: aws-lambda, getstream-io

I didn't find any posts related to this topic. It seems natural to use Lambda as a getstream backend, but I'm not sure if it heavily depends on persistent connections or other architectural choices that would rule it out. Is it a sensible approach? Has anyone made it work? Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

While you can build an entire website only in Lambda, you have to consider the followings:

- Lambda behind API Gateway has a timeout limit of 30 seconds and a Payload size limit (both received and sended) of 6MB. While for most of the cases this is fine, if you have some really big operations or you need to send some really big datas (like a high resolution image), you can't do it with this approach, but you need to think about something else (for instance you can send an SNS to another Lambda function with higher timeout that can do all this asynchronously and then send the result to the client when it's done, supposing the client is capable of receiving events)
- Lambda has cold starts, which in terms slow down your APIs when a client calls them for the first time in a while. The cold start time depends on the language you are doing your Lambdas, so you might consider this too. If you are using C# or Java for your Lambdas, than this is probably not the best choice. From this point of view, Node.JS and Python seems to be the best choices, with Golang rising. You can find more about it [here](https://mikhail.io/serverless/coldstarts/aws/). And by the way, you can now specify a `Provisioned Throughput` for your Lambda, which aims to fix the cold start issue, but I haven't used it yet so I can't tell if there is any difference (but I'm sure there is)
- If done correctly you'll end up managing hundreds of Lambda functions, while with a standard Docker Container under ECS you'll manage few APIs with multiple endpoints. This point should not be underestimated, as on one side it will make changes easier in the future, since lambda will be small and you'll easily find the bug and fix it, but on the other side you have to move across these functions, which if you don't know exactly which lambda is responsible of what can be a long process
- Lambda can't handle sessions as far as I know. Because after some time the Lambda container gets dropped, you can't store any session inside the Lambda itself. You'll always need a structure to store the session so it can be shared across multiple Lambda invocations, such as some records in a DynamoDB table or something else, but this mean that you have to write the code for this, while in a classic API (like a .NET Core one) all of this is handled by the language itself and you only need to store or retrieve items from the session (most of the times)

So... yeah! A backed written entirely in Lambda is possible. The company I work in does it and I must say is a lot better, both in terms of speed and development time. But those benefits comes later, since you need to face all of the reasons I listed above before, and is not as easy as it could seem

Comment: I'm not sure why this was voted down, but I guess that's Stackoverflow for you. Thanks for upload limits. I do want to upload movies and images, so that's a thing. I do have a lot of serverless experience so that part doesn't scare me, I just don't want to go down a path getstream won't support well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use AWS Lambda as backend and integrate with Stream API there.

Building an entire application on Lambda directly is going to be very complex and requires writing lot of boiler plate code just to enforce some basic organization and structure to your project.

My recommendation is use a serverless framework to do this that takes care of keeping your application well organized and to deploy new versions (and environments).

Serverless is a good option for that: https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/intro/